# boost::asio::async_read_some run in parent thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asyncsocket

I am writing an efficient socket server. The intention is good overall throughput. I use the main thread as the listener. It `async_accept` a client and add the socket to a queue. There's a dispatcher threads picks up a socket, who is ready to be read from, from the queue and added to one of the worker threads' queue. I keep a pool of worker threads. A worker thread will do actual read/write.

I use `async_accept` in my listener. To find out which socket is ready for read, I use async_read_some in my dispatcher. This idea works, but with a problem. My `io_service.run()` is called in listener, so the handler of `async_read_some` in dispatcher, is actually run in the listener thread.

Here's my code:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;

std::queue<std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>> q_sock;
boost::mutex m_log1;
boost::condition_variable m_cond1;
boost::mutex::scoped_lock m_lock1 = boost::mutex::scoped_lock(m_log1);
sem_t _sem_sock;

enum { max_length1 = 1024 };
char data_1[max_length1];

void handle_read1(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> sock, const boost::system::error_code& error,
  size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    printf("handle_read1 : error : %s : %d, thread id is: %ld, pid : %d \n", error.category().name(), error.value(), (long int)syscall(SYS_gettid), getpid());

    boost::asio::write(*(sock.get()), boost::asio::buffer(data_1, bytes_transferred));
}


void sock_dispatch() {
    int v_size = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> curr_sock;

    printf("sock_dispatch started. The ID of this of this thread is: %ld, pid : %d \n", (long int)syscall(SYS_gettid), getpid());

    while(1) {

        while(1) {
            sem_wait(&_sem_sock);
            v_size = q_sock.size();
            sem_post(&_sem_sock);

            if(v_size <= 0)
                m_cond1.timed_wait(m_lock1,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
            else
                break;
        }

        sem_wait(&_sem_sock);
        curr_sock = q_sock.front();
        q_sock.pop();
        sem_post(&_sem_sock);

        curr_sock->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_1, max_length1),
        boost::bind(handle_read1, curr_sock,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

}

class session
{
    public:
      session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : sockptr(new tcp::socket(io_service)) {}

      void start()
      {
            printf("START NEW SESSION   The ID of this of this thread is: %ld, pid : %d \n", (long int)syscall(SYS_gettid), getpid());

            sem_wait(&_sem_sock);

            q_sock.push(sockptr);

            sem_post(&_sem_sock);

            m_cond1.notify_all();
      }

      std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> sockptr;
};

class server
{
    public:
      server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
          acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
      {
        session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(*(new_session->sockptr.get()),
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));

        printf("WAITING TO ACCEPT: The ID of this of this thread is: %ld, pid : %d \n", (long int)syscall(SYS_gettid), getpid());

      }

      void handle_accept(session* new_session,
          const boost::system::error_code& error)
      {
          new_session->start();
          new_session = new session(io_service_);
          acceptor_.async_accept(*(new_session->sockptr.get()),
              boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }

    private:
      boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
      tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sem_init(&_sem_sock, 0, 1);

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std;
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(sock_dispatch));

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

This code is modified from a boost::asio example, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp. And the client code is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp.

When a client connects, the output of server:

```
WAITING TO ACCEPT: The ID of this of this thread is: 3843, pid : 3843 
sock_dispatch started. The ID of this of this thread is: 3844, pid : 3843 
START NEW SESSION   The ID of this of this thread is: 3843, pid : 3843 
handle_read1 : error : system : 0, thread id is: 3843, pid : 3843
```

In this case the dispatcher thread id is 3944, but the handle_read1 is run in thread 3843.
Ideally, handle_read1 should run in dispatcher, so it won't block accept in listener.

Any idea what I should do to achieve this? Or there's better design for the whole thing at all :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need specific handlers being invoked in specific threads, then use different `io_service` objects.  For example, the `acceptor` could be constructed with `io_service1`, and the sockets could be constructed with `io_service2`.  The main thread could then perform `io_service1.run()`, while the threads in the thread pool perform `io_service2.run()`.

With that said, mixing asynchronous and synchronous functionality can be rather tricky.  In most asynchronous programs I have worked on, there is rarely a need to dedicate a thread to specific asynchronous chains.

---

Overall, I think the conceptual design is fine, but I have a few suggestions for the implementation:

- The `q_sock` consumer and producer code is a mix of of higher level and lower level constructs.  The use of the condition variable is a bit nonidiomatic, and it begs the question as to why `sem_t` is being used in place of `boost::mutex`, and locks.  For example, the following consumer and producer code:

  ```
  // Consumer
  while(1)
  {
    sem_wait(&_sem_sock);
    v_size = q_sock.size();
    sem_post(&_sem_sock);

    if (v_size <= 0)
      m_cond1.timed_wait(m_lock1, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
    else
      break;
  }
  sem_wait(&_sem_sock);
  curr_sock = q_sock.front();
  q_sock.pop();
  sem_post(&_sem_sock);

  // Producer    
  sem_wait(&_sem_sock);
  q_sock.push(sockptr);
  sem_post(&_sem_sock);
  m_cond1.notify_all();
  ```

  Could be rewritten without the use of `sem_t`, and be a bit more idiomatic based on the Boost.Thread's [`condition_variable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) documentation.  Consider the alternative:

  ```
  // Consumer
  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_log1);
  while (q_sock.empty())
  {
    m_cond1.wait(lock);
  }
  curr_sock = q_sock.front();
  q_sock.pop();
  lock.unlock();

  // Producer
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_log1);
    q_sock.push(sockptr);
  }
  m_cond1.notify_all();
  ```
- It is unclear as to what functionality `session` provides.

  - It only seems to function as a means to allocate a socket, and place it into the queue.  Why not just allocate the socket directly and have the caller place it into the queue?
  - `session::sockptr` is managed via a smart pointer, but `session` is not.  With `session` not being managed via a smart pointer, a memory leak occurs in `server::handle_accept`, as the handle to `session` is lost in the reassignment.

  Identify what functionality `session` is to provide, and design the interface around that.

  - If it is intended to provide encapsulation, then non-member functions, such as `handle_read1`, may need to become member functions.
  - If `session` has its own asynchronous chain, and is providing itself to handlers, then consider using [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).  The Boost.Asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) provides an example usage, as does a few of the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).
- At the moment, [`async_read_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) is not indicating which socket is ready to be read.  By the time the `ReadHandler` has been invoked, data has been read.

  This is the fundamental difference between a Proactor and Reactor.  If you need Reactor style operations, then use [`boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html).  See [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) documentation for more details.  However, there are consequences to each approach.  Thus, it is critical to understand these consequences so that the best decision can be made.
- With Boost.Asio providing event demultiplexing through high-level constructs, the `sock_dispatch` thread may seem impractical. The `session::start` member function could initiate the asynchronous read on the socket.  This minor change would eliminate the need for `q_sock`, and all synchronization constructs in the example code.
- Examine why the synchronous write must be used.  In the case of echo clients, as shown in the example, it is often the case that asynchronous writes can be used by controlling the flow of the asynchronous chain itself to remove resource contention.  This allows for each connection to have its own buffer, that can be used for both reading and writing.
- Do not pre-optimize.  Asynchronous programming is inherently harder to debug as a result of the inverted flow of control.  Trying to pre-optimize for throughput will just exacerbate the complexity issue.  Once the program is working, perform throughput test.  If the results do not meet the requirements, then profile to determine the bottleneck.  In my experience, most servers with high throughput will be I/O bound far before being CPU bound.

Comment: Thanks twsansbury, it works when I use another io_service obj in the thread. And I realize I don't need async for my listner thread, I can use a loop for that. I can just use a io_service for my dispatcher, in order to find out which socket is ready for read.\n As you mentioned, I should't mix async & sync, I feel a bit horrible about this design as well. First, do you think I should separate listener and dispatcher at all? If I put them together, dispatch handler will stop acceptor, which affect throughput, isn't it?

Comment: And is there alternative to find out which socket is ready other than async_read_some? it's kinda manipulated way to me.

Comment: @eltonsky: I have updated the answer to provide some overall suggestions, and hopefully answer your additional questions.